# Alternative to HTTPS : using SFTP and LAMP

Tags: php, security, https, sftp, lamp

For my project :

- i download files from remote server (with sftp)
- with php i do some treatments on these files (locally with LAMP)
- i finally upload the modified files to the remote server (with sftp)

You can ask me why i don't use the php files directly on the remote server.

when i do this :  browsing, send get, send post, etc... all this traffic is visible on http.
so i need to use **https**, but you need to buy certificate.

the solution is like i explain : use sftp for files transfert, and use LAMP (locally) for all treatment.

Everything seems good for me. what about you about this tricky idea ?

**My browsing using php scripts (get, post, etc...) is not sent over the internet with http, it is do locally in LAMP. Only file upload and download are sent, and are using the secured SFTP.**

I Think that this way my traffic is protected, what do you think ? Is it a good or a bad idea ?

Comment: Your explanation suggests that we exactly know what you are doing with those files and why. We don't.

Comment: Why LAMP? Don't need it

Comment: What i'm doing is open html file to modify them. @marekful

Comment: LAMP, because i want to use php. you can also use WAMP or EasyPHP,.. @EdHeal

Comment: You can just use Php and not have all the other stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use https, but you need to buy certificate

Not true, there is at least one free SSL cert company, and another on the way this summer.

Also, if only a small number of known users are using the certificate, it doesn't need to be signed by an authority. You can use a self-signed one, configure it as trusted on your client, and boom, encrypted channel!

Seeing as you're only doing file transfers, SCP is probably simpler than SFTP.

Comment: very good! i just found https://letsencrypt.org/ !! I can't wait to use this ;)